# How to escape double quotes and colon in ACK in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ack

I am using Ack version 2.04, in PowerShell. I want to search texts like **"jsonClass":"Page"** (quotes included) inside text files.

I can't seem to get the quoting and escaping correct.

```
ack -c --match '"jsonClass":"Page"'
```

It doesn't work in PowerShell. I guess ack's picking up the single quotes as well.

Escaping the double quotes gives an invalid regex error:

```
ack -c --match "\"jsonClass\":\"Page\""
  Invalid regex '\':
  Trailing \ in regex m/\/ at C:\CHOCOL~1\lib\ACK2~1.04\content\ack.pl line 315
```

I tried the literal option as well, but I think ack's interpreting the colon as file parameters.

```
ack -c -Q --match "jsonClass":"Page"
  ack.pl: :Page: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

I am using PowerShell v2.

Comment: what is ack command/cmdlet/function ?

Comment: @arashzgh http://beyondgrep.com/

Comment: I am using powerShell 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ack` is a function it could happen that `-c` is interpreted by PowerShell. Can you test the following?

```
ack '-c' '--match' '"jsonClass":"Page"'
```

`-c --match` should be interpreted as `--match` is the value of parameter `c` in function `ask`.

If it's an EXE file, try:

```
ack -c --match '\"jsonClass\":\"Page\"'
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be the issue.

Comment: I tried -c without the quotes on simpler patterns and it's returning expected results. `ack -c -Q --match "Page"`

Comment: `ack` is a Perl script/module. The backslashes are needed for when the string is processed by Perl. Either `'\"jsonClass\":\"Page\"'` or ``"\`"jsonClass\`":\`"Page\`""`` will work.

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers yes i had also zeroed down on the first pattern, via trail and error. Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Good answer, but to fully replicate _raw_ argument `"\"jsonClass\":\"Page\""`, I suggest enclosing the contents of the single-quoted string in double quotes: `'"\"jsonClass\":\"Page\""'`.
It makes no difference with the string at hand, which doesn't contain whitespace, but in other cases it may. To add to @AnsgarWiechers' clarification: on Windows, `ack` is implemented as a batch file (`ack.cmd`) that calls `perl.exe` with script `ack.pl`.

Answer (score 6):

To complement [JPBlanc's effective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058586/45375) with a **PowerShell v3+** solution:

When **invoking external programs** such as `ack`
, use of the so-called **stop-parsing symbol, `--%`**, makes PowerShell **pass the remaining arguments through *as-is***, with the *exception* of expanding `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references such as `%PATH%`:

```
ack --% -c --match "\"jsonClass\":\"Page\""
```

This **allows you to focus on the escaping rules of the target program only**, without worrying about the complex interplay with PowerShell's own parsing and escaping.

Thus, in PowerShell v3 or higher, the OP's own 2nd solution attempt would have worked by passing `--%` as the first parameter.

See [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx).

---

Note that the *exact* equivalent of the above command without the use of `--%` (that also works in **PSv2** and is generally helpful **if you want to include PowerShell-expanded variables / expressions in other arguments**) would look like this:

```
ack -c --match '"\"jsonClass\":\"Page\""'
```

That is, the **entire argument to be passed as-is is enclosed in *single* quotes**, which ensures that PowerShell doesn't interpret it.

<sup>Note the inner enclosing `"` that aren't present in JPBlanc's answer (as of this writing). They guarantee that the argument is ultimately seen as a *single* argument by `ack`, even if it contains whitespace.</sup>

Comment: I am using PowerShell v2, and the above escaping isnt solving it, because it seems the args passed to ack is also including the back quote

Comment: @sas1138: I've rewritten the answer. It is now only helpful to PSv3+ users, but since you haven't tagged your post as v2-only (please keep it that way now), I figured I'd show a PSv3+ alternative that may be helpful to future readers. (The mistake of my original answer was that I was trying to fix your _PowerShell solution attempt_ rather than solve your original problem; note that the backticks would _not_ have been passed to `ack`, however, because the backtick is PS' _own_ escape char.)

Comment: thanks, i tried to edit, but i didn't have enough privileges to edit posts yet

Comment: @sas1138 You should always be able to edit your _own_ posts, however (if you're signed in). (Just to amend my previous comment: I've since added a PSv2 solution too.)

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell you can always use `'` quote to handle inner `"` without problems.

But if you need to use `"` for a string (to interpolate a variable, for instance), you can escape them with `

```
$myvar = 'test'
$formatted = "{`"value`":`"$myvar`"}"

Write-Host $formatted
# output: {"value":"test"}
```